# Help bounding sums of reciprocals of square-free positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Fix positive integers $k$ and $n$. Let $N_1,\dots,N_r$ be all the integers less than or equal to $n$ that are squarefree and have exactly $2k$ distinct prime factors. Define $S = \sum_{j=1}^r \frac1{N_j}$.

For each $1\le j\le r$, choose a factorization $N_j = P_jQ_j$ into two numbers with exactly $k$ prime factors each, satisfying $Q_j > P_j$ (so that $P_j < \sqrt n$). These choices are certainly not unique.

By construction, it is straightforward that

$$S = \sum_{j=1}^r \frac1{P_jQ_j} > \sum_{j=1}^r \frac1{\sqrt n Q_j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{Q_{i}}.$$

Empirical trial and error leads me to conjecture that there exists a choice of factorizations such that
$$S<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{P_{i}}.$$
However, I have not been able to prove it. Any hint or help would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the question to try to make the intent clearer; please check that I haven't introduced any errors in doing so.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you very much! I think that your edit is perfect and everything is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a counterexample.

For $(n,k)=(9,1)$, since we have $r=1,N_1=2\times 3,P_1=2$ and $Q_1=3$, we get
$$S\color{red}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{P_{i}}.$$

I could not find any other counterexamples.

So, it seems true that for every $(n,k)$ such that $(n,k)\not=(9,1)$, there exists a choice of factorizations such that $$S<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{P_{i}}\tag1$$

I cannot prove this, but I got a sufficient condition for $(1)$.

Let $R_i$ be the product of the first $k$ primes of $N_i$.

Then, we want to prove that
$$S<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{R_{i}}\tag2$$

We have $$S\lt \frac{r}{T_{2k}}\tag3$$ where $T_{k}$ is the product of the first $k$ primes.

Also, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{R_{i}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\cdot \frac{r}{\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}-1}{2}\rfloor}\tag4$$
where $\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}-1}{2}\rfloor$ is the largest integer $x$ such that $x(x+1)\le n$.

From $(3)(4)$, a sufficient condition for $(2)$ is
$$\frac{r}{T_{2k}}\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\cdot \frac{r}{\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}-1}{2}\rfloor}$$
i.e.
$$T_{2k}\gt \sqrt n\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}-1}{2}\right\rfloor\tag5$$

So, for a given $k$,
$$T_{2k}\le n\le U_{2k}$$
is a sufficient condition where $U_{2k}$ is the biggest $n$ satisfying $(5)$.

**Examples** :

- For $k=1$, $6\le n\le 8$ is sufficient.
- For $k=2$, $210\le n\le 224$ is sufficient.
- For $k=3$, $30030\le n\le 30131$ is sufficient.

Comment: thanks! Even not being a proof, a little step forward. And your counterexample is perfect, lets see if we can prove that there exists a choice of factorizations such that $S\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{P_{i}}$ for any given $(n,k)$